# Where is data stored in React.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-services, redux

For an interview, I was asked ,"where is data stored in React.js?"  I tried saying state, props, and React doesn't store data.  I'm not sure what answer he was looking for.  What's the best way to answer this question?  Note, he's primarily a Java programmer.

Comment: What an absurd question. Regarding data flow, understanding state and props are all you need. Don't sweat being unable to answer that question.

Answer (score 4):

Without his mindset it is kinda of hard to say...

- Hardware - It's stored in memory
- Classic React - Props and State are completely legitimate answers
- React-Redux - It's stored in the 'store'

I think this is a poor question to ask an interviewee without any real context.  Java programmer or not, it sounds like he doesn't entirely understand what he is talking about.  You might have dodged a bullet not working for that company.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this question is to check different ways to store data for use in a component and when we can use them.  Choices are:  state, store, this and static.

1. Keep UI state and transitory data (such as form inputs) in local ***state***.
2. The Redux ***store*** is great for keeping application state rather than UI state. Keep data that you intend to share across components in store.
3. Use ***this*** to store things that shouldn’t trigger a re-render.
4. ***Static*** methods and properties are rarely used, and should be used only for utility functions that all components of a particular type would need.

Comment: I think this might have been the best response I could have given. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would have said React can use a combination of sessionStorage, localStorage, state, store, and this, to hold data, however storing data would be whatever database you setup to use it with.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of React, nowhere, since react does not store any data

Redux: stores data in redux store, which internally is js object(s) stored in the memory (RAM). Depending on what level of detail you want to go into, take your pick. ridiculous interview question btw.

Answer (score 1):

Was that exactly how the question was asked? It's a bit of a weird one since react doesn't really store things as in persisting. That is all lost once a page changes or the component dismounts for that matter.

If so, I would say that the component's state is the best place to store data regarding the component itself, such anything that was received from the user input, in the case of a controlled component.

I wouldn't think it is props, since props aren't supposed to store data per say, but pass it down to another component, but that is a bit nit-picky I suppose, since you could argue it stores data coming from another component.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the question I was asked.  I mentioned that as soon as you refresh the page it would disappear so it doesn't store data.  He didn't appear to like that answer.